# redefinition of module 'Firebase Core' and redefinition of module 'Firebase'

Tags: firebase

I added Firebase-ios-sdk from Github to my Swift project.  After installing in Xcode via 'Add Package'.  I see the following errors when building.  My project is not a react project.

FirebaseCore.modulemap
redefinition of module 'Firebase Core'. ( and a matching issue...)
Module.modulemap
redefinition of module 'Firebase'

[image]

If I uninstall the package, everything builds and runs fine.

Any help is very much appreciated.